# Laravel 5.1 file upload, File's same name for folder and database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My controller code where i store the file name into a database table and also moving the file to a folder.

The issue is that i am storing the original name of a file in database table, in contrast i am moving files with uniqueid() and time() . It will arise issues in future. because in database table file name and moved file are with different names.

```
if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
            $pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
            $mobile->photo1 = $pic[0]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo2 = $pic[1]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo3 = $pic[2]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo4 = $pic[3]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo5 = $pic[4]->getClientOriginalName();
                foreach ($pic as $k=>$file){
                    if(!empty($file)){
                        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . uniqid() . '-' . $k . '-laptop');
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use something like that:

```
if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
    $pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
    foreach ($pic as $k=>$file){
        if(!empty($file)){
            $temp = $k+1;
            $mobile->photo.$temp = time() . uniqid() . '-' . $k . '-laptop';
            $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $mobile->photo.$temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. your code is not storing the image names in database !

Comment: After foreach add $mobile->save();

Comment: Maybe try to change code to:
$temp = 'photo'.($k+1);
$mobile->$temp = ..
 $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $mobile->$temp);

Answer (score 0):

You can store both names in your database. Store one as `original_name` and one as `generated_name` for example.

And you can serve the file with the original name by retrieving it from the database if you want to let your users download it. It should look like this:

```
$photo = Photo::find(1);
return response()->download($photo->generated_filename, $photo->filename);
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex for the answer but i need to change the original file name then store it in the database and then move the file as well.

Comment: Let me see if I understand it right: I upload the file `somephoto123.jpg`, you store it as `/var/www/laravel/storage/photo456.jpg`, save its name in the database and then move it again?

Comment: i want to `somephoto123.jpg` . So i want to add `time()` and `uniqueid()` with its name to avoid naming collision. Database stored name and the moved image name should be the same. 
Note : I am taking 5 images from user, See the code.